# Lock down content blocks from being edited

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

We have build a few free forms to drag and drop into a template we built. Essentially the non-technical user will be dragging these content blocks from specific folders and editing them. I noticed the "Save Block" on the left of these free form blocks, as if you were to make changes to them, you could override the block you pulled from.

Is there a way to lock these blocks down so non technical users can't override what we have already built?

Answer (score 2):

You could limit the user's ability to update existing assets through permissions:

[image]

This allows you to stop the user updating existing content, but they can save their own content.

[image]

If you have shared content enabled in your account, you can share your content block and apply permissions to specific to the item:

[image]